# Remove header on one page

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

I use moderncv to create my cv. There I include a pdf document with the includepdf command. The problem is that I defined a fancyheader and that this header is also on the included pdf, but I do not want this.

I called my pagestyle myfancy and I use it with the command:

```
\pagestyle{myfancy}
```

Then my pages follow where I want to have my documents with the header. Then I include the pdf via:

```
\includepdf{Test.pdf}
```

Then I have the header, but I don't want to have this header.

According to different posts I tried

```
\pagestyle{plain} 
\fancyhf{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

But the all do not work, the header is still there. Where is my mistake?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pagecommand` like this:

```
\includepdf[pages=1-6,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}]{pgfmanual.pdf}
```

Change appropriate style (`plain` or `empty`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}    %% made thick for visibility
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{My header}
\lfoot{\emph{My footer}}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\kant[1-4]
\includepdf[pages=1-6,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}]{pgfmanual.pdf}
\section{Another section}
\kant[5-8]
\end{document}
```

MWE with `modercv`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\moderncvstyle{casual}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\includepdf[pages=1-6,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}]{pgfmanual.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]